# Homotopy type of a sphere

Tags: homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a CW-complex of finite dimension.

Suppose that $\pi_k(S^n)$ is isomorphic to $\pi_k(X)$ for all $k\geq 0$, where $n>1$.

Certainly, $\dim X\geq n$. It is easy to show that $X$ has homotopy type of $S^n$ provided $\dim X \leq n+1$.

**Question:** is it true for any $X$ of finite dimension? If not, is there a counter-example?

Comment: Sorry if this is ignorant, but can you suggest  examples of $\pi_k (S^n) \neq 0$ for $k>n $?

Comment: @gary: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_groups_of_spheres

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: My bad, I had forgotten about the Hopf fibration.

Comment: Something is wrong with your question. If you want to find an $X$ such that $\pi_k(S^n)$ isomorphic to $\pi_k(X)$ for all $k \ge 0$ and $n>1$ then, for example, you are asking that both the nontrivial group $\pi_2(S^2) \approx \mathbb{Z}$ and the trivial group $\pi_2(S^3)$ be isomorphic to $\pi_2(X)$, which is not possible.

Comment: @LeeMosher I think $n$ is supposed to be fixed once you fix $X$.